# Joomla not displaying the content on the website

Tags: joomla

I have installed template called smartone in joomla.But when i preview it on the site only logo and footer is visible.Help please.I have tried to intall some plugins but still is not visible

Comment: This is not a programming question. Turn error reporting to development (server tab of global config) and then disable whatever plugin is causing he problem. If you still need help please use the joomla stackexchange site [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0):

1. Check how is avaialable positions in template;
2. Check how positions yours modules are.
3. Check your first page in Menu defined home with "yelloow star" 
   I hope this helps you.